# Add css property to elements :hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can I add css property to elements hover state.

I know how to add background to an element, what I need is to add background to an elements :hover state.

I have a `<div class="myDiv"></div>`

I can add css background `$('.myDiv').css('background', 'red');`

When using `('.myDiv').hover((function(e) { $(this).css('background', 'red');` the background changes on hover, but it stays this way even when not hovering over element.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking to do this with javascript? Is there an unknown factor stopping you from using css's `:hover` selector?

Comment: Generally, applying styles using JavaScript is a bad practise. Please do use CSS’ `:hover` selector or add/remove classes.

Comment: Yes there is a reason, as I am generating background with js.

Answer (score 7):

`.hover()` method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

```
$('.myDiv').hover(function(e) { $(this).css('background', 'red'); },
                 function() { $(this).css('background', 'none'); } );
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lmj001/)

Comment: hm, that's probably something with my code..though `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` works just fine..

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it using css no need for any script,

```css
.myDiv:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events instead.
Or write your current code like this:

```
('.myDiv').hover((function(e) { $(this).toggleClass('redBackground') });
```

Here you have to define  the css class 'redBackground'.

Answer (score 0):

hover function comprises two state. hover state and hover out state.

```
$('.myDiv').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'white')
    }
);
```

For more info check [this](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) link.

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave events. [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/5ytdyrr5/)

```
$( ".myDiv" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $( this ).css("background","red");  
});
$( ".myDiv" ).mouseleave(function() {
  $( this ).css("background","none");  
});
```

Comment: could you please explain how this adds any value against any of the previous answers?

Comment: This seem to work, while having `.hover` with two functions inside won't work in my case (not sure why) but would probably be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use css.No need any jquery.

```
.myDiv:hover { 
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```